# Version error in Google Colab notebook for ISR package

Tags: python, image, google-colaboratory

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.0.0 (from ISR) (from versions: 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.4, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.0.0 (from ISR)
```

This is the error i'm facing when i try to do

```
!pip install ISR
```

in my google colab notebook

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by version incompatibility and I have faced a similar problem.

If you haven't installed TensorFlow yet, install it first:

`pip install tensorflow`

if you have already installed TensorFlow, you can just skip the dependency:

`pip install ISR --no-deps`

I solved the same issue using this command.